# Apple Watch app rejection for "Booting to White Screen"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple-watch, ios8.2

My app just got rejected, and the reason was that the Apple Watch Extension was "Booting to White Screen" on Apple Watch. They sent me a screencapture of Apple Watch screen that just has white screen. Not much information.

I honestly have no clue where I went wrong... seeing that the app runs fine on both iPhone and the Simulator.

I don't have an Apple Watch to test this with or any logs on real device to show you although I wish I could give as much information on this question.

I don't have any info I can supply other than the fact that they rejected the app, and app doesn't seem to run on real device.

I don't think it would be a code issue seeing that the First Screen in my app is just a few buttons for menu, without much things happening.

Could anyone give me any insight to how to approach this problem? or has anyone had a similar issue?

Here's the response from Apple.

> 2.2 Details
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone
>   running iOS 8.2 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> Specifically, upon review we found the Apple Watch app will boot to
>   white screen display upon launch.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise
>   and resubmit your app for review.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a
>   device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).
>   For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous
>   version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
>   this message in the Resolution Center to provide information on how
>   these features were intended to work.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce the issue, you should appeal it in the resolution center and request more details. You might want to attach videos and screen shots of it working fine in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've appealed it in the resolution center to see if they could provide any additional information for me to take the right direction.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering or having the same issue... it was really a stupid mistake. I didn't put the images used for Apple Watch in the correct asset catalog with correct target membership. That's why it was displaying the images correctly on simulator, but not on real Apple Watch, since images weren't embedded within the app. These kind of things needs to be double-triple checked before submitted to app store because it doesn't show on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. You should post that as an Answer, below, instead of as a comment.

Comment: So I assume it should be checked for containing app, watch extension and watch app? To be 100% sure it will be displayed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just in case anyone is wondering or having the same issue... it was really a stupid mistake.

I didn't put the images used for Apple Watch in the correct asset catalog with correct target membership. That's why it was displaying the images correctly on simulator, but not on real Apple Watch, since images weren't embedded within the app.

These kind of things needs to be double-triple checked before submitted to app store because it doesn't show on the simulator.

Comment: Hi, @seyong i also faced same issue...can you please correct me if i did any mistake.  In target membership of an image i checked(selected checkmark) of 'watch app' and 'watch extension' and left 'main or root app' unchecked...so, is it required to check main app too....is that the reason for my app to get rejected???

Comment: Hi @TejaKumarBethina, what fixed the issue for me was to: 1. Set Watch Images target membership to watch app and watch extension, which you already did. 2. Put those images in a new asset catalog, with target membership watch app 3. Use the images in asset catalog, not the ones that has .png or .jpg in the storyboard. After that, Apple had no issue approving my app. Good luck!